# Why won't 'system' call in perl return?

Tags: linux, perl, tcsh

New, radical development on this.  Go to the end and read.

perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
RH6

I have a perl script that makes a system() call which runs a tcsh script but, for one user, it won't return from that system call.  The code is something like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "about to make the system call...\n";
$rv = system("tcsh aa.csh");
print "system call finished, return val = $rv\n";
exit;
```

And the aa.csh script...

```
echo "In shell script"     
mkdir foo
source someotherscript.csh
ln -s xxx yyy
echo "In shell script, about to exit"
exit
```

This script runs to completion for all users but one.  He sees this...

```
about to make the system call...
In shell script
In shell script, about to exit
```

And it just hangs.  If I hit ^C, it completes..

```
system call finished, return val = 2
```

Funny thing is, it prints the "In shell script, about to exit", with the very next step being "exit", but it just doesn't do it, at least not for this one user. All the commands that come before it are, in my mind, irrelevant because it reached this "about to exit" message.  It appears that the ^C is interrupting the shell script (which won't exit) and returning to the perl script which proceeds to completion.

So my question has to do with learning why it hangs for this one guy.  There's got to be something in his environment that's causing the problem but I don't know what.  And what does a return value of "2" mean?  May mean nothing because I interrupted with a ^C.

Thanks for any help

NEW DEVELOPMENT

This has nothing to do with perl.  If the aa.csh script is just...

```
exit
```

And the user runs...

```
tcsh aa.csh
```

It hangs.

What's up with that?

Moderator, should this thread be deleted and should I repost (because this is so radically different) ?

Comment: What does `someotherscript.csh` do?

Comment: I'd have to look into it.  But, thinking that it made it past that and down to the exit command, does it really matter?  Also, others run this script with no problem.

Comment: OK, new development, something unrelated to perl.  User can't even do this...

    # This is the aa.tcsh script...
    exit

Now, when the user does a "tcsh aa.tcsh", it hangs.
Will augment original post.

Comment: The first line of a tcsh script should normally be `#!/bin/tcsh -f` . The `-f` tells the shell not to source the user's `.login` file. Or you can invoke the script as `tcsh -f aa.csh` rather than `tcsh aa.csh`. If adding `-f` fixes the problem for that one user, then the problem is in that user's `.login` (or some other startup file).

Comment: please read about [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Clean up everything. Have that user log out (and perhaps reboot the machine) and try again.  If it's the same they should remove (and save!) their shell configuration files and try again. If that works, then they can start putting back their config a little at a time.

Answer (score 1):

problem was a corrupted .history file.

Answer (score 0):

Have him run

```
which exit
```

from a `tcsh` prompt. If it doesn't say something like

```
exit: shell built-in command
```

but rather something like

```
exit:   aliased to sleep 99999
```

then you've found your problem.

If `exit` is really the last line of your `aa.csh` script, then it is redundant, and you also try to use a version of the script that doesn't call `exit` at the end.